# Character mesh not moving with armature

Tags: animation

After setting up animations I copied the first character's animation data, its rotation and location to the second character (two identical character with same mesh and armature).

The second character has its graph editor and keyframes copied correctly but the whole arms and legs mesh is on a standstill. While the torso and head works.

It shows that the armature is moving and moving the armature manually only moves its armature and not the mesh along with it.

Is this not the right way to copy animations?

Comment: Hello maybe share your 2 characters?